# the click event is not working after pagination.so the 11th record cant be approve/delete by admin .we are using ace admin template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is the ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
</script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- page specific plugin scripts -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- ace scripts -->
<script src="assets/js/ace-elements.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/ace.min.js"></script>

<!-- inline scripts related to this page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#simple-table").DataTable();

    $(".viewrecord").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"processes.php",
            type: "post",
            async: false,
            data:{action:"view_image_info",post_id:$(this).attr('id')},
            success:function(res){
                $(".page-content .row .col-xs-12").html('');
                $(".page-content .row .col-xs-12").html(res);
                $(".page-content").append('<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><button type="button" id="backbutton" class="width-10 btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i><span class="bigger-110">Back</span></button></div></div>');
            }
        });             
    });

    $(".deleterecord").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"processes.php",
            type: "post",
            async: false,
            data:{action:"delete_image",post_id:$(this).attr('id')},
            success:function(res){
                if(res == 'success'){
                    alert("Image deleted successfully");
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    alert("Some error occured while deleting the image");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $(".approvevideo").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"processes.php",
            type: "post",
            async: false,
            data:{action:"approve_image",post_id:$(this).attr('id')},
            success:function(res){
                if(res == 'success'){
                    alert("Image approved");
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    alert("Some error occured while approving the image");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $(".page-content").on('click','#backbutton', function(){
        window.location.reload();
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
    @$total_count_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(post_id) as totalrows FROM `yoga_posts` WHERE `post_type`='image' ");
    $totalrows=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($total_count_query)){
        $totalrows = $row['totalrows'];
    }

    if($totalrows==0){
?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">No Records Found</td>
    </tr>
<?php   

    } else {
        @$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `yoga_posts` WHERE `post_type`='image' ");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <label class="pos-rel">
                <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
                <span class="lbl"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $row['post_title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_username_from_id($row['user_id']);?></td>
        <td>
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <a class="blue viewrecord" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i>
                </a>

                <a class="red deleterecord" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i>
                </a>

                <?php if($row['post_status']=='pending'){?>
                <a class="green approvevideo" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok bigger-130"></i>
                </a>
                <?php } ?>
<?php 
    @$total_count_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(post_id) as totalrows FROM `yoga_posts` WHERE `post_type`='image' ");
    $totalrows=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($total_count_query)){
        $totalrows = $row['totalrows'];
    }

    if($totalrows==0){
?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">No Records Found</td>
    </tr>
<?php   

    } else {
        @$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `yoga_posts` WHERE `post_type`='image' ");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <label class="pos-rel">
                <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
                <span class="lbl"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $row['post_title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_username_from_id($row['user_id']);?></td>
        <td>
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <a class="blue viewrecord" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i>
                </a>

                <a class="red deleterecord" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i>
                </a>

                <?php if($row['post_status']=='pending'){?>
                <a class="green approvevideo" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok bigger-130"></i>
                </a>
                <?php } ?>
<?php 
    @$total_count_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(post_id) as totalrows FROM `yoga_posts` WHERE `post_type`='image' ");
    $totalrows=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($total_count_query)){
        $totalrows = $row['totalrows'];
    }

    if($totalrows==0){
?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">No Records Found</td>
    </tr>
<?php   

    } else {
        @$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `yoga_posts` WHERE `post_type`='image' ");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <label class="pos-rel">
                <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
                <span class="lbl"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $row['post_title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_username_from_id($row['user_id']);?></td>
        <td>
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <a class="blue viewrecord" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i>
                </a>

                <a class="red deleterecord" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i>
                </a>

                <?php if($row['post_status']=='pending'){?>
                <a class="green approvevideo" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok bigger-130"></i>
                </a>
                <?php } ?>
<?php 
    @$total_count_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(post_id) as totalrows FROM `yoga_posts` WHERE `post_type`='image' ");
    $totalrows=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($total_count_query)){
        $totalrows = $row['totalrows'];
    }

    if($totalrows==0){
?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">No Records Found</td>
    </tr>
<?php   

    } else {
        @$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `yoga_posts` WHERE `post_type`='image' ");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <label class="pos-rel">
                <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
                <span class="lbl"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $row['post_title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_username_from_id($row['user_id']);?></td>
        <td>
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <a class="blue viewrecord" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i>
                </a>

                <a class="red deleterecord" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i>
                </a>

                <?php if($row['post_status']=='pending'){?>
                <a class="green approvevideo" href="#" id="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>">
                    <i class="ace-icon ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok bigger-130"></i>
                </a>
                <?php } ?>
```